# The value $N$ modulo $D$ in binary

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary

Given an integer $N$ represented in binary by $b_5b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0$ and $D = 2^4$. The value $N$ modulo $D$ in binary is given by:

A) $b_3b_2b_1b_0$

B) $b_4b_3b_2b_1b_0$

C) $b_5b_4b_3b_2$

D) None of these answers

Please explain me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you take a decimal number modulo $10^6 = 1000000$, only the rightmost six digits matter.

(Think a car odometer. If you have only six digits on your odometer reading, you don't know if the car's been driven $1,234$ miles, or $1,001,234$ miles.)

In fact, the answer *is* the rightmost six digits.

Can you take it from here?